# Or is indicated as an invalid syntax, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, pygame

Would you take a look at the following code which I copied from Make Games with Python.2-Raspberry Pi, page 33? I ran it on Visual Studio and got the first error was (line 73):

```
if (playerVX > 0.0 and playerVX < maxSpeed) or
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS

# pygame variables
pygame.init()

windowWidth = 800
windowHeight = 800

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Keyboard!')

# square variables
playerSize = 20
playerX = (windowWidth / 2) - (playSize / 2)
playerY = windowHeight - playerSize
playerVX = 1.0
playerVY = 0.0
jumpHeight = 25.0
moveSpeed = 1.0
maxSpeed = 10.0
gravity = 1.0

#keybpard variables
leftDown = False
rightDown = False
haveJumped = False

def move():
    global playerX, playerY, playerVX, playerVY, haveJumped, gravity

    #move left
    if leftDown:
        # if we are already moving to the right,reset
        #the moving speed and invert the direction
        if playerVX > 0.0:
            playerVX = moveSpeed
            playerVX = -playerVX
        # make sure our square does not leave our
        #window to the left
        if playerX > 0:
           playerX += playerVX

    #move right
    if rightDown:
        #if we are already moving to the left,reset
        #the moving speed again
        if playerVX < 0.0:
            playerVX = moveSpeed
        #make sure our square does not leave our
        #window to the right
        if playerX + playerSize < windowWidth:
            playerX += playerVX

    if playerVY > 1.0:
        playerVY = player * 0.9
    else:
        playerVY = 0.0
        haveJumped - False

   # is our square in the air?
   # better add some gravity to bring it back down
    if playerY < windowHeight - playerSize:
        playerY += gravity
        gravity = gravity * 1.1
    else:
        playerY = windowHeight - playerSize
        gravity = 1.0

    playerY -= playerVY

    if (playerVX > 0.0 and playerVX < maxSpeed) or
        (playerVX < 0.0 and playerVX > -maxSpeed):
        if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown)
            playerVX = playerVX * 1.1


# how to quit our program
def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

while True:
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,0,0),
    (playerX, playerY, playerSize, playerSize))

        #get a list of all enets that happened since
        #the last redraw
        for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.k_LEFT:
                leftDown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rightDown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if not haveJumped:
                    haveJumped = True
                    playerVY += jumpHeight
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quitGame()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                leftDown = False
                playerVX = moveSpeed
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rightDown = False
                playerVX = moveSpeed

    if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
        quitGame()

move()
pygame.display.update()
```

Is there anything thing wrong with my code please? And how would I change it? I have tried to deleted the line which indicated error and typed it again, while the error still exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line

```
if (playerVX > 0.0 and playerVX < maxSpeed) or
```

is not a complete statement, so you need to indicate to Python that it continues onto the next line. You can do this with more parentheses:

```
if ((playerVX > 0.0 and playerVX < maxSpeed) or
    (playerVX < 0.0 and playerVX > -maxSpeed)):
```

or using a backslash

```
if (playerVX > 0.0 and playerVX < maxSpeed) or \
    (playerVX < 0.0 and playerVX > -maxSpeed):
```

Subsequently, the line

```
if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown)
```

is missing a colon `:`

Comment: Thanks so much ! I just add more parentheses and the new error is :line 75
    if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown)
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax, how should I deal with it please?I am a beginner and just copied down code from book, sorry for these low level questions

Comment: @ruihuiliu The `if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown)` line is missing a colon.

Comment: Thanks so much ! Your advices help me a lot ! I just checked the code and rewrote it according to error indication, while it turned out a white screen window and informed new error , I think there might have some problem with the code itself, I am thinking of changing a new book now

Answer (score 0):

## I corrected your code and yes, the code itself is wrong.

I have all your code locally and I changed it so that it doesn't throw any errors. I'm using python 3.6 and the newest version of pygame.

I also left comments where it says `if playerVY > 1.0` because there is a var that doesn't exists in the actual context and I changed it to another var. The square moves to fast so I might be doing a mistake, this is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS

# pygame variables
pygame.init()

windowWidth = 800
windowHeight = 800

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Keyboard!')

# square variables
playerSize = 20
playerX = (windowWidth / 2) - (playerSize / 2)
playerY = windowHeight - playerSize
playerVX = 1.0
playerVY = 0.0
jumpHeight = 25.0
moveSpeed = 1.0
maxSpeed = 10.0
gravity = 1.0

#keybpard variables
leftDown = False
rightDown = False
haveJumped = False

def move():
    global playerX, playerY, playerVX, playerVY, haveJumped, gravity

    #move left
    if leftDown:
        # if we are already moving to the right,reset
        #the moving speed and invert the direction
        if playerVX > 0.0:
            playerVX = moveSpeed
            playerVX = -playerVX
        # make sure our square does not leave our
        # window to the left
        if playerX > 0:
           playerX += playerVX

    #move right
    if rightDown:
        # if we are already moving to the left,reset
        # the moving speed again
        if playerVX < 0.0:
            playerVX = moveSpeed
        # make sure our square does not leave our
        # window to the right
        if playerX + playerSize < windowWidth:
            playerX += playerVX

    if playerVY > 1.0:
        # You tried to find the variable "player" so I guessed you meant playerVY
        # You had "playerVY = player * 0.9"
        # I don't refactor the code because I'm not sure you wanted what I made.
        playerVY = playerVY * 0.9
    else:
        playerVY = 0.0
        haveJumped = False

   # is our square in the air?
   # better add some gravity to bring it back down
    if playerY < windowHeight - playerSize:
        playerY += gravity
        gravity *= 1.1
    else:
        playerY = windowHeight - playerSize
        gravity = 1.0

    playerY -= playerVY

    if ((playerVX > 0.0 and playerVX < maxSpeed) or
        (playerVX < 0.0 and playerVX > -maxSpeed)):
        if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown):
            playerVX *= 1.1


# how to quit our program
def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

while True:
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,0,0),
        (playerX, playerY, playerSize, playerSize)
    )

        #get a list of all enets that happened since
        #the last redraw
    for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():
       if  event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if  event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                leftDown = True
           if  event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rightDown = True
           if  event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if not haveJumped:
                    haveJumped = True
                    playerVY += jumpHeight
           if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quitGame()

       if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                leftDown = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rightDown = False

            if event.key in {pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT}:
                playerVX = moveSpeed

       if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
            quitGame()

    move()
    pygame.display.update()
```

If you want, you can use apschedular (a module that you would have to install using pip) to move every 0.04 seconds. you'ld have to add
`from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler`
at the top and

```
sched = BackgroundScheduler()
sched.start()
sched.add_job(move, "interval", seconds = 0.04)
```

just after the function move()

#### Edit:

Another thing, the variables doesn't follow the naming convention of PEP-8.